# Meaning of orange number left to the "review" button for 10k+ users

Tags: support, bug, review, 10k-tools

[image]

We all know that the orange bubble with the white number (here: <kbd>**330**</kbd>) represents the number of **Suggested edits** for users with **3k+ reputation**.

But I have recently (today) reached **10k reputation** and now can't find any number that would fit on this any more. Even the sum of all displayed review queues does not match ( 256+28+27+1 = 312 ), same if I add the review items on Meta (1 at that time).

What is the new behaviour of the "review indicator" for users with greater than 10k reputation?

Comment: Welcome to 10K! And blame caching!

Comment: Can it be really that difficult to sum up 5 integer numbers? >.<

Comment: Yes. (I don't want to talk about it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the number of questions or answers awaiting review.

The number is not always correct. :)

Comment: Adding the `bug` tag to my question then! ;D